MS Access Count 0 not visible
I have a table with columns Date, Login and SLA (takes value 0 or 1).
I have a simple question see below. The problem is that it doesn't return records if the count is 0. I've already tried almost everything and nothing :-( Please advise.
SELECT Date, Login, Nz(Count(SLA)), SLA
FROM t_source_org_frt
GROUP BY Date, Login, SLA;


Maybe try with: Count(Nz(SLA, 0)) instead?

I tried it and unfortunately it doesn't work either.

Why do you include SLA in the SELECT and GROUP BY? Does every record have value in SLA? Could provide sample data and desired result as formatted text tables.

Use Count(*):
SELECT 
    [Date], Login, Count(*) As SLACount
FROM 
    t_source_org_frt
GROUP BY 
    [Date], Login


The COUNT function, applied to a field, returns the number of records (in the respective group) where the field is not NULL. The SLA field is probably never empty, so a count of 0 would mean a non-existent group, but the query can't output something that isn't there.
You probably want to count the records with SLA=1, so try something like this:
SELECT Date, Login, Sum(Iif([SLA] = 1, 1, 0)) As SLAs
FROM t_source_org_frt
GROUP BY Date, Login

